# APK not working made from Android Studio V 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I have updated my Android Studio from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3.

Now, when I try to install APK generated in \app\build\outputs\apk, the App gets installed but it just flicks and exists.

It used to work fine before but it's not working since yesterday, and I have tried 2-3 different projects also but no use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Your manual way of generating APK
>   is not  generating the correct APK, so i am Suggesting these way to
>   generating APK for Manual Install:

**For Debug Build**

- Delete you build folder inside the App folder.
- Goto `Build>Build APk`. it will generate .apk file in your
  `app>build>output>apk` directory.
- COPY it your device and install manually.

**For Release Build**

- Delete you build folder inside the App folder.
- Goto `Build>Generate Signed APk` and provide recomended Details, make sure your `Build type : release` and have checked both signature version `v1(jar signature)` and `v2(full apk signature)` . it will generate .apk file in your
  `app>build>output>apk` directory.
- COPY it your device and install manually.

Comment: Getting error: please select at least one of the signature versions to use