# Not able to install signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I have an app in play store, with

```
versionCode 19
versionName "19"
```

Now I build an APK with new vesrion code

```
versionCode 20
versionName "20"
```

and signed with release key.

I installed the live app from play store on my device and tried to install the signed APK over that, but it shows an error as below,

`“App not installed” 
“The package appears to be corrupt”`

Can anybody advice me on this how to solve.

> Note: Both apks are signed with same release key, There was change in
>   Launcher Activity but now I updated that to Same Old name but still
>   the error appears.

Comment: follow this to generate signed APK....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591639/apk-not-working-made-from-android-studio-v-2-3-3/44591854#44591854

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild it and generate signed apk.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar it is not solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

try this.
in your manifast.

```
     <activity android:name="your new Launcher Activity" />

     <activity-alias
          android:name="your old Launcher Activity"
          android:targetActivity="your new Launcher Activity">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>


     </activity-alias>
```

Comment: I already refactored my Activity name the same old name, then does it worth adding an alias.